# UICollectionView Max Cell Spacing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a simple `UICollectionView` setup in my storyboard with a prototype cell. I have set all section insets to 10, top, left, bottom and right.

The important bit, I have set the minimum spacing for cells and lines to 5. When I run the app and have for example 2 cells in my collection view, the cells are not aligned left with spacing of 5px between each cell.

Instead, there is a 20px space between each cell, left to right. Why would this be? No matter what I set the spacing to be, it always is 20px.

Any idea why this would be? All I want is my cells to be spaced as I set it, i.e. 5px gaps.

**EDIT:**

I have thought of a far simpler, and better way of asking. Can I set a maximum cell spacing? Clearly we can set a minimum, but that won't stop the spacing being larger than I want it to.

Comment: Ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the width and height of your cells because your cells won't expand or collapse based on the insets.
use the `-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`method to size your cells according to your needs.